# Fullscreen VideoView in the background

Tags: java, android, android-video-player

I have an ImageView that displays an image in fullscreen in the background. This is done in this way.

```
public void handleImage(String imageLocation) {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mediaView);
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);

    layout.addView(image);

    Uri imageLocUri = Uri.parse(imageLocation);
    image.setImageURI(imageLocUri);
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
}
```

Now I need to do the same for video, but VideoView does not have .setScaleType().

The video needs to be playable on click, and I will be displaying buttons and stuff on top of the video.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to retain the video aspect ratio or stretch it?

Comment: I think I need to stretch it. I mean, when I record a video the preview is fullscreen, I'd just like to make it look the same basically. But overlay buttons and a big play button in the middle that controls the video.